# Java BeanDefinitionStoreException on Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to rewrite an application using Spring Boot 2 (specifically 2.1.5.RELEASE). Previous version used 1.5.7.RELEASE. We are switching database platforms, thus the rewrite. The startup class in both new and old are nearly identical, both attempting to create a bean from another library. It works in 1.5.7, but in 2.1.5, it fails with the following message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process 
import candidates for configuration class [com.company.consumer.ConsumerRecoveryConfiguration];
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect
annotated methods on class com.company.consumer.RecordRecovery
```

Here's what the startup class looks like in old and new:

Old:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.company.core",
    "com.company.something",
    "com.company.platform",
    "com.company.config"},
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type =
        FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.company.common.diag.*"))
@Import({SomeClass.class, ConsumerRecoveryConfiguration.class,
    ConsumerRetryConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:build.properties")
public class SomeApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean(name = "someDbTimingLogger")
  public TimingLogger getSomeDbTimingLogger() {
    return new TimingLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("timing.someDb"));
  }

  @Bean(name = "timingLogger")
  public TimingLogger getTimingLogger() {
    return new TimingLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("timing.consumer"));
  }

  @Bean(name = "kafkaTimingLogger")
  public TimingLogger getKafkaTimingLogger() {
    return new TimingLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("timing.kafka"));
  }

  @Bean(name = "parser")
  public Parser<GenericMessageModel> getSomeModelParser() {
   return new Parser<>(GenericMessageModel.class);
  }
}
```

New:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.company.core",
    "com.company.something",
    "com.company.platform",
    "com.company.config"},
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.REGEX,
            pattern = "com.company.common.diag.*"
    ))
@Import({ ConsumerRecoveryConfiguration.class,
        ConsumerRetryConfiguration.class })
@PropertySource("classpath:build.properties")
public class SomeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "timingLogger")
    public TimingLogger getTimingLogger() { return new TimingLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("timing.consumer")); }

    @Bean(name = "kafkaTimingLogger")
    public TimingLogger getKafkaTimingLogger() { return new TimingLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("timing.kafka")); }

    @Bean(name = "parser")
    public Parser<GenericMessageModel> getSomeModelParser() { return new Parser<>(GenericMessageModel.class, null); }
}
```

The Kotlin class mentioned in the nested exception is as follows (minus its numerous private methods):

```
@Component
class RecordRecovery(val producer: KafkaProducer<String, String>, val kafkaProducerSettings: KafkaProducerSettings,
                     val recoverySettings: RecoverySettings, val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) {

    val random = ThreadLocalRandom.current()!!


    companion object {
        val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RecordRecovery::class.java)
    }

    fun recoverRecords(records: ConsumerRecords<String, String>, exception: Exception) {
        recoverRecords(records.map { it.value() ?: StringUtils.EMPTY }, exception)
    }

    fun recoverRecords(records: List<Any>, exception: Exception) {
        error(metaDataFor(records.count()), LOGGER, "Recovering {} records", records.count())
        val filteredRecords = records.map {  createRecoveryRecord(it) }
                .filter{ it != null }
                .map { recordToJson(it) }
                .filter { removeNulls(it) }
                .mapIndexed { index, it -> toEmergencyDataWrapper(it!!, exception, index) }
                .mapNotNull {toJSONStringOrNull(it)}
                .map {toProducerRecord(it)}
                .map { republish(it) }
                .toList()
        info(metaDataFor(filteredRecords.count()), LOGGER, "After filtering, recovering {} records", filteredRecords.count())
        filteredRecords.map { await(it) }
    }
}
```

And here's the ConsumerRecoveryConfiguration class (also Kotlin) in question:

```
@Configuration
@Import(KafkaProducerConfig::class, RecoverySettings::class, RecordRecovery::class)
class ConsumerRecoveryConfiguration
```

The class has no body whatsoever. I'm assuming that importing the other classes causes Spring to basically use those as the body.

I'm still somewhat green when it comes to Spring, so I'm struggling to see why it stopped working when I changed to SB 2. Any suggestions about where I should look or what might help me figure this out?

EDIT:

Here is the full stacktrace as requested:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.company.consumer.ConsumerRecoveryConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.company.consumer.RecordRecovery
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:596)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:302)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:586)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:302)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.company.SomeApplication.main(SomeApplication.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class com.company.consumer.RecordRecovery
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:392)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:317)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:586)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:158)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: *"Any suggestions about where I should look or what might help me figure this out?"* Show us the full stacktrace of the error. It might show in what way it "failed to introspect annotated methods". Also, error is about `com.company.consumer.RecordRecovery`, which is not in any of the scanned packages, and you didn't provide us with the code for it, so what did you expect us to do about it?

Comment: Sorry. I am usually better at remembering those things. I added both.

Comment: So, `ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject`, doesn't that tell you everything you need to know? You're missing the jar file that contains that class. See https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see that. Seems odd that with all of the dozens of libs that I have in the build.gradle file that something as basic as that would've already been included. Putting that in fixed it. Thanks!